# when to use Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate. i have read below line.

```
Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP
```

Please help me when to use `Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

**These are generally used with the Result Set Transformers in hibernate.  Read the [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904) or see an [example](http://relation.to/2133.lace).** A ResultTransformer is a nice and simple interface that allows you to transform any Criteria result element.

E.g. you can make any Criteria result be returned as a java.util.Map or as a non-entity Bean.

You can read the example for the **ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP** [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations). That is,

*The kittens collections held by the Cat instances returned by the previous two queries are not pre-filtered by the criteria. If you want to retrieve just the kittens that match the criteria, you must use a ResultTransformer.*

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .createCriteria("kittens", "kt")
        .add( Restrictions.eq("name", "F%") )
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
    .list();
Iterator iter = cats.iterator();
while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Map map = (Map) iter.next();
    Cat cat = (Cat) map.get(Criteria.ROOT_ALIAS);
    Cat kitten = (Cat) map.get("kt");
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of pre-filtered by the criteria?

Comment: For info, instead of `sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)`, i had to use `sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)`. Else i will get `Use static access with "org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification" for "ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP"`.

Answer (score -2):

```
 query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ContainerStatusModel.class)).list();
```

Comment: Hi, please expand on *why* this code answers the question. Code snippets without context are not considered good answers.