# Spring MVC - get a single value from a List in the controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem i don't know well how to manage...

In my controller I have a method

```
@RequestMapping(value = {path+"/illuminazione"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String lightsSituation(ModelMap model){
    String pageTitle ="Stato Luci";
    List <Illuminazione> illuminazione = illuminazioneService.showLightsSituation();
    model.addAttribute("illuminazione", illuminazione);
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", pageTitle);
    model.addAttribute("cssActiveIll", cssActiveIll);
    return path+"/illuminazione";
}
```

This method simply makes a List of Objects taken from the DB. In this way I can easily pass all the model to my view to display the objects. The problem is that in the fields I have two timestamps values and I want to display in the view the duration between them.
I have no problem with the duration function and I managed to do the calculation directly in the JSP page, but i'd prefer to do this in the controller and simply pass to the model the result of the calculation (is it a correct approach?). How can I take from the List just the two values i need so to add them to the model?

I thought of making a new function into the service implementation class but it looks to me a uber solution...

This is **Illuminazione.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "illuminazione", catalog = "SMARTPARK")
public class Illuminazione implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idEvento;
    private Luce luce;
    private Date dateTime;
    private Date lastDateTime;
    private boolean isLit;

    public Illuminazione() {
    }

    public Illuminazione(int idEvento, Luce luce, Date dateTime, Date lastDateTime, boolean isLit) {
        this.idEvento = idEvento;
        this.luce = luce;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.lastDateTime = lastDateTime;
        this.isLit = isLit;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_evento", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdEvento() {
        return this.idEvento;
    }

    public void setIdEvento(Integer idEvento) {
        this.idEvento = idEvento;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_luce")
    public Luce getLuce() {
        return this.luce;
    }

    public void setLuce(Luce luce) {
        this.luce = luce;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm")
    @Column(name = "date_time")
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return this.dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "isLit", nullable = false)
    public boolean isIsLit() {
        return this.isLit;
    }

    public void setIsLit(boolean isLit) {
        this.isLit = isLit;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm")
    @Column(name = "last_date_time")
    public Date getLastDateTime() {
        return lastDateTime;
    }

    public void setLastDateTime(Date lastDateTime) {
        this.lastDateTime = lastDateTime;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

As suggested by @reos I could add a `duration` field in my Illuminazione.java, which now has

```
public String getDuration(){    
        DateTime sd = new DateTime(getDateTime());
        DateTime ed = new DateTime(getLastDateTime());
        Period period = new Period(sd, ed);
        long days = period.getDays();
        long hours = period.getHours();
        long minutes = period.getMinutes();
        long seconds = period.getSeconds();

        this.duration=days+" giorni - "+hours+" ore - "+minutes+" minuti - "+seconds+" secondi";

        return duration;
    }
```

The problem is that my `illuminazioneService.showLightsSituation();` comes from a DaoImpl which is a normal SQL query (i cannot do this query with Criteria or HQL to work with objects)

```
public List<Illuminazione> showLightsSituations() {

        String query = "select i.id_evento, i.id_luce, i.last_date_time, l.numero_luce, l.nome_luce, ill.MaxDate, i.isLit ";

        query += "from illuminazione i inner join  luci l on i.id_luce= l.id_luce ";
        query += "inner join (SELECT `id_luce` as numeroLuce2, max(date_time) as MaxDate from illuminazione i2 group by `i2`.`id_luce`) ill ";
        query += "on i.id_luce = ill.`numeroLuce2` and i.`date_time` = ill.MaxDate order by i.`id_luce` asc";
        SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
        q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List<Illuminazione> lista = q.list();
        return lista;
    }
```

In this way, when i send the model to the JSP view i have only the fields I selected with the query and I cannot recall duration in this way `${ill.duration}` because it's empty
This is an extract of the JPS

```
<c:forEach items="${illuminazione}" var="ill">

        <tr>
            <td><div class="list-field">
            <fmt:formatDate value="${ill.MaxDate}"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm" />
            </div></td>
       <td><div class="list-field">
            <fmt:formatDate value="${ill.last_date_time}"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm" />
            </div></td>
        <td><div class="list-field">${ill.duration}</div></td>

    </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can use a wrapper object like IlluminazioneDTO which have class variable durationBetweenDates and in a for each statement create this object and set the field with this value. But this cause performance problem if you have more than 10K value at this list. If it is i suggest to you write another query and in sql calculate the difference and return it in a field directly. This way sql do it with better performance.

Comment: I don't like too the idea of the wrapper. Doing the calculation in SQL directly is an option, but i can return a non formatted result, using TIMESTAMPDIFF for instance. I get simply a number and I should format it in JSP right?

Comment: What is the content of Illuminazione ?

Comment: edited the question to add it @reos

Comment: I would recommend you to add a method getDuration() to your Illuminazione class

Comment: Thank you @reos this could be an excellent solution, but I've updated the question because I think i lost some step in the implementation...

Comment: You could just calculate the duration and call a setDuration() method on each of the Illuminazione beans.  Then add these updated beans to the list for display.  This solution would work fine unless you have a *really* high number of beans.  I can post a solution if this is unclear.

Comment: thank you @bphilipnyc, if you can help me with an example, i will be glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely a more efficient way to do this, but I am just showing you the concept.  This should get you done quickly.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {path+"/illuminazione"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String lightsSituation(Model model){
    String pageTitle ="Stato Luci";
    List <Illuminazione> illuminazione = illuminazioneService.showLightsSituation();

    //to be very clear with the example, we create a new list that will have
    //the updated duration.  
    List <Illuminazione> definitivo = new ArrayList<>(illuminazione.size());

    for (Illuminazione fagioloJava : illuminazione) {
         DateTime start = fagioloJava.getDateTime();
         DateTime end = fagioloJava.getLastDateTime();

         //let your controller just route requests  
         //and provide the model attributes; 
         //put the duration calculation in a service class

         String duration = IlluminazioneService.getDuration(start, end);
         fagioloJava.setDuration(duration);
         definitivo.add(fagioloJava);
    }

    model.addAttribute("definitivo", definitivo);
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", pageTitle);
    model.addAttribute("cssActiveIll", cssActiveIll);
    return path+"/illuminazione";
}
```

Service:

```
public class IlluminazioneService {
    public static String getDuration(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
       Period period = new Period(start, end);
       long days = period.getDays();
       long hours = period.getHours();
       long minutes = period.getMinutes();
       long seconds = period.getSeconds();
       //if this needs to be internationalized, 
       //then I wouldn't return it this way.  
       //You could have a field for days, hours, minutes, etc. 
       //and get the rest from a Spring message (resource) bundle.
       return days+" giorni - "+hours+" ore - "+minutes+" minuti - "+seconds+" secondi"; 
    }
}
```

Illuminazione:

```
//add this.  
//transient because we don't need to persist this:
@Transient 
private String duration;

//getter and setter
```

Now obviously, if you have trillions of `Illuminazione` beans, then iterating through them will take time.  But in most cases, this solution will be perfectly fine.  We see this method used in projects all the time.

Comment: thanks @bphilipnyc that's just the method I was looking form, it's clear and 'should' do what I need, my only problem is that i'm getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to it.besmart.models.Illuminazione it.besmart.controller.IlluminazioneController.lightsSituation(IlluminazioneController.java:58)` which is this part `for(Illuminazione javaBeans : illuminazione) {`

Comment: I don't see a `HashMap` in your code.  Are you sure that `illuminazioneService.showLightsSituation()` returns a `List`?

Comment: You're setting the query to return a `Map` with `q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);`.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909550/when-to-use-criteria-alias-to-entity-map-in-hibernate

Comment: If you need to return a `Map`, then the process should be the similar - iterate over a `Map` rather than a `List`.  But regardless, your service method `showLightsSituations()` needs to change to reflect the correct type.

Comment: And I'd probably rename your original service class `IlluminazioneDaoImpl` instead of `IlluminazioneService.`  Then you can create an interface called `IlluminazioneDao` so that if you need to add another implementation later, it's as simple as implementing the Dao interface and you won't have to touch anything else.

Comment: mmm... i'm having some problems with the map creation because i cannot understand how to gather Map and List in the controller... changing all my code from List to Map I think it's too much for my skill atm...